# Komma bei oder-Aufzählung?

Tags: comma

Man betrachte folgenden Satz:

> Jedem Symbol sei zugeordnet, ob es ein Relations-, Funktions-, oder Konstantensymbol ist.

Meine Frage ist nun:

Wird zwischen "Funktions-" und "oder Konstantensymbol" wirklich ein Komma gesetzt? Oder müsste es richtig heißen

> Jedem Symbol sei zugeordnet, ob es ein Relations-, Funktions- oder Konstantensymbol ist.

Answer (score 4):

Gemäß § 72 des amtlichen Regelwerks zur deutschen Rechtschreibung steht in Aufzählungen gleichrangiger Wörter vor *oder* kein Komma.

> Sind die gleichrangigen Teilsätze, Wortgruppen oder Wörter durch *und, oder, beziehungsweise/bzw., sowie (= und), wie (= und), entweder … oder, nicht … noch, sowohl … als (auch), sowohl … wie (auch)* oder durch *weder … noch* verbunden, so setzt man kein Komma.
>
> Dies betrifft
>
> (…)
>
> (2) gleichrangige Wortgruppen oder Wörter in Aufzählungen (…)
>
> (…)